# Running through paragraphs in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have an VBA function where I want to remove every paragraph that does not have the same first number introduced by the user. In addition, it removes that number of the paragraph.

Example:

Paragraph 1: "03 text1"

Paragraph 2: "12 text2"

Paragraph 3: "22 text3"

If the user introduces the number 1, the document must only keep the following paragraph:"2 text2"

The thing is, once I remove the first number of the paragraph, the `for loop` thinks that **the modified paragraph is a new one!** so currently everything is removed in this last example.

Here is the code of my function:

```
    Dim par As Paragraph
    Dim firstCharacter As String
    
    ' Run through every paragraph of the document
    For Each par In doc.Paragraphs
    
        'define first character of the paragraph
        firstCharacter = Left(Trim(par.Range.Text), 1)
        
        'check if the first character is numeric
        If IsNumeric(firstCharacter) Then
        
            'if the number is the same, just remove the number, if not, remove the whole paragraph
            If firstCharacter = aux Then
                par.Range.Text = Trim(Mid(par.Range.Text, 2))
            Else
                par.Range.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next par
```

Example of input:

Paragraph 1: "03 text1"

Paragraph 2: "12 text2"

Paragraph 3: "22 text3"

User introduces 1

Output:

"2 text2"

Comment: Can you provide more detail about you function. What variable `doc` is initialized

Comment: This is a common problem encountered by newcomers to VBA.  When you delete an item from a collection the items in the collection are automatically renumbered.  So, for example if you delete Item(3) then what was Item(4) is renumbered to Item(3).  So when for each comes along and asks for item(4) it gets the old Item(5) (because 5 was renumbered to 4).  Thus when deleting items from a collection you have to enumerate backwards, typically 'For myIndex = Collection.Count to 1 step -1'.

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate paragraphs with index in reverse order

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim par As Paragraph
    Dim firstCharacter As String
    Dim doc As Document, i As Long
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim aux As String: aux = "1" ' for testing
    ' Run through every paragraph of the document
    For i = doc.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set par = doc.Paragraphs(i)
        '    For Each par In doc.Paragraphs
        'define first character of the paragraph
        firstCharacter = Left(Trim(par.Range.Text), 1)
        'check if the first character is numeric
        If IsNumeric(firstCharacter) Then
            'if the number is the same, just remove the number, if not, remove the whole paragraph
            If firstCharacter = aux Then
                par.Range.Text = Trim(Mid(par.Range.Text, 2))
            Else
                par.Range.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Word handle if an element is removed from a collection, while it is processing it.

One workaround to collect all the relevant paragraphs and at the end put it back in the document.

```
Sub mi()
Dim par As Paragraph, firstCharacter As String
Set doc = ActiveDocument
' Run through every paragraph of the document
aux = 1
For Each par In doc.Paragraphs

    'define first character of the paragraph
    firstCharacter = Left(Trim(par.Range.Text), 1)
    
    'check if the first character is numeric
    If IsNumeric(firstCharacter) Then
    
        'if the number is the same, just remove the number, if not, remove the whole paragraph
        If firstCharacter = aux Then
            buffer = buffer & Trim(Mid(par.Range.Text, 2))
        Else
            par.Range.Delete
        End If
    Else
        buffer = buffer & par.Range.Text    
    End If
Next par
doc.Range.Delete   ' this is needed because the last paragraph would be kept if corresponds to the test.
doc.Range.InsertAfter buffer
End Sub
```